# rails belongs_to has_many please explain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following:

`User` model with columns:

```
id     user_id     password     created_at     updated_at
```

`Store` model with columns:

```
id     store_id    store_name   create_ad      updated_at
```

Basically a user can belong to multiple stores. So I would want to get a query like "get all the stores that the user belongs to"

Relationships I've made are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store, :foreign_key => "store_id"
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :user, :foreign_key => "store_id"
end
```

are these correct?

Ultimately I want to find out whether a userid, password and storeid should be able to login.

So how can I use the `find_byXXX` on this ? so If I get a row back with passed in userid, password and storeId...I would know whether user should be able to login?

I noticed that belongs_to and has_many questions have been asked before but I was not able to understand well from those questions. maybe answers specific to my problem will help...

Answer (score 0):

So you've said that a user belongs to many stores. How many users belong to a single store?
If the answer is more than 1, then what you need is `has_and_belongs_to_many` and a third database table. The table will essentially contain pairs of (`store_id`, `user_id`).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Although it is not required by Rails, it is recommended that you create a model for this relation and make the relation bidirectional on that model. You will thank yourself later.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :userstores
    has_many :stores, :through => :userstores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :userstores
    has_many :users, :through => :userstores
end

class UserStore < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :store
end
```

Comment: @BennyG "and make the relation bidirectional on that model." Are you speaking of two `has_many :through` relations?

Comment: The new model (UserStore) will have two `:has_one` relations. And yes, you can add `has_many :through` relations for convenience to both the User and Store model.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. Your tables and model should be as follows:

User Table:

```
id password created_at updated_at
```

Store Table:

```
id store_name created_at updated_at
```

Join Table (called stores_users):

```
store_id user_id
```

In your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

To get a user's stores:

```
User.stores
```

See [the rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001836) for more information.

Comment: User.stores does not return my anything it says Undefined method 'stores'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making a lot of false assumptions about how ActiveRecords works on a basic level, so I would recommend reading the official and very straightforward [ActiveRecord Associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).