# Rails how to create a different table for each user

Tags: migration, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have two tables *account* and *display_colors*. The *display_colors* table has 10 default ids with color codes. If one user changes the color the colors for all user gets changed.

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to create a different table for each user or any other options I have without changing the actual logic of my frontend.

I tried using association *belongs_to* and *has_many* where *display_colors* have a column *account_id* but it is getting changed on each and every update.

**display_color.rb**

```
  #TODO: Add for account level
  belongs_to :account
  def self.update_colors(colors)
    import colors, on_duplicate_key_update: { conflict_target: [:id], columns: [:max_range, :color_code] }
  end

  def self.color_code(conf)
    rounded = (conf * 100).round
    where("min_range <= ? AND max_range >= ?", rounded, rounded).first.try(:color_code)
  end
end
```

**Account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :display_colors

  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  def self.default
    where(name: 'default').first
  end
end
```

The screenshot shows the db table looks like. I have 10 columns in there those 10 must be unique to a user with default values for each account at the beginning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2GHh.png

Comment: Could you post your models? Does each User have many DisplayColors, or how are your associations set up?

Comment: Could you use an `after_create` callback on each user to create the 10 default colors, then allow users to change those colors?

Comment: @thesecretmaster me being new to rails do not know much about those things could you please reference me with some best resources to learn those or even showing how to do that would be grateful

Comment: I am not sure if you need a different table for each user, from my perspective you need some primary and foreign keys. I think you were on the right track with has_many and belongs _to relations, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137437/rails-belongs-to-has-many-please-explain) and [in the Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Maybe it helps.